# How to convert an excel file to .csv file?

Tags: c#, windows-ce, smart-device

I'm developping an application for Honeywell Dolphin 6100, a mobile computer with a barcode scanner that uses Windows CE 5.0 like OS.

I want to create a little application responsible of the convertion of an excel file to .csv file.

**Is it possible in Win CE ? if so, any help on it ?**

thank you in advance !!

**Note**: I'm using VS2008 and I'm working on Windows 7.

Comment: have you tried this http://exceldatareader.codeplex.com/ ?

Comment: where would the excel file be coming from?

Comment: I don't whether it will work on **Mobile platform** or not, But try to rename the file **extension** from `.xls` or `.xlsx` to `.csv` and **save** the file programatically.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Have you done any research on your own?

Answer (score 6):

You can do this by using saveas() method in Excel:

```
wbexceltocsv.SaveAs("c:\Filename.csv", Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlCSV)
```

Follow link:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/yuanwang200409/how-to-convert-xls-file-into-csv-file-in-C-Sharp/

As well this link can be helpful to you:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/246772/Convert-xlsx-xls-to-csv

Comment: I don't think he can use excel interop with wince

Answer (score 0):

There's no reasonable way to do this on a Windows CE device.  Presumably the CSV file is coming from a PC, so you must convert it on the PC (using an interop library or tool) before sending to the device.